# Story about fantasy creatures as computers

Tags: story-identification, urban-fantasy

I'm trying to recall a story I read several years ago.  It was an urban fantasy with Greek gods involved in the plot.  Our protagonist was a magical hacker of some sort, and he had a familiar, a goblin who could turn into a computer with access to magical networks.  Some of the more powerful characters had "troll mainframes."  The primary antagonist was Eris, and she had computers of her own: Apples.  (Yes, the author really went there.)

Does this ring any bells for anyone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're describing the "[WebMage](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/975638.WebMage)" series by Kelly McCullough.

Per [N.Trachta's](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0441014259) review:

> Mr. McCullough does a very good job of merging our current world with
>   that of Greek mythology. The Fates are very real, the Furies bite at
>   you, and Eris is the goddess of discord (as Mr. McCullough points out
>   nicely, the hackers goddess). **The fascinating thing in this series is
>   that the gods and goddess's use computers to execute their magic,
>   something that Mr. McCullough sells very nicely by having the gods
>   computers being living trolls (mainframes) and goblins (laptops/pcs).**

[image]

Comment: Awesome. That's it!